# Summation of Infinite Series as given below

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

SERIES:

$1+(1+a)b + (1+a+a^2)b^2 + (1+a+a^2+a^2)b^3..........$

Given: $|a|<1;  |b|<1$

Approach:

$1.1+(1+a)b + (1+a+a^2)b^2 + (1+a+a^2+a^2)b^3..........$

$T_n = (1 * a^{n-1} + S_{n-1})b^n-1$

$S_{n-1} = \sum_{k=1}^n a^{n-2}$

$S_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {(1 * a^{n-1} + S_{n-1})b^n-1}$

Kindly help me in further simplification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1+a+a^2+\ldots+a^n=\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}$$
The series can be written as
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}b^n=\frac{1}{1-a}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1-a^{n+1}\right)b^n=$$
$$=\frac{1}{1-a}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b^n-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^{n+1}b^n\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{1-a}\left(\frac{1}{1-b}-a\cdot\frac{1}{1-ab}\right)=\frac{1}{(1-b) (1-a b)}$$